# Symfony 4: Dotenv::populate returns none

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am trying to run a Symfony4 app on production and I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv::populate() 
must be an instance of Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\void, 
none returned in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:95
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(57): 
    Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->populate(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/public/index.php(12): 
    Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->load('/var/www/html/s...')
#2 {main}
    thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 95
```

On local the app is running fine. Once it moves to production, it breaks.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 7):

And is production running PHP5.x, or 7.0?  The [void return type is only available/reserved from PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php), and so it would think it could be a class in the same namespace - which does not exist either. [Symfony 4 requires PHP 7.1.3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/e251993ce2fc22c311a85d8de3ceb0127d96ce8b/composer.json#L19)

Comment: Time for me to upgrade my PHP version then.  I too ran into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue when I tried to run Symfony 4 on Ubuntu 16.04 server. In my situation I forgot to enable the new php version in the Apache server after upgrading from v7.0 to v7.2 . I hope below details would help you to check on your production server.

Run following command to see which php version is active.
`ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*`

Disable previously installed php version.
`sudo a2dismod php7.0`

Enable new installed php version.
`sudo a2enmod php7.2`

Do not forget to restart Apache server.